# PHP loop through mysql results with two selects and create an aligned html table

Tags: php, html, mysql

I am having issues creating a table which is aligned like this in PHP:

```
 TH   HOME                               AWAY
 TH | num    | name    | teamname |    | num    | name    | teamname |
 TR | hsknum | hskname | hsktname |    | asknum | askname | asktname |
```

I im finding it impossible to get the two results to align in the table with foreach or while loops.

edit 2:

HOME or AWAY could be empty or 1 -> 14 entries (results for HOME or AWAY) and this is where my code skills fall apart.

Thanks.

edit1:

My PHP loop is:

```
<?php while (( $resultshome = $rowh->fetch()) || ($resultsaway = $rowa->fetch())) { ?>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                    <?php
                       if ( !empty($resultshome) ) { ?>
                      <?php echo $resultshome['hsknum']; ?>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                      <a href="/runner/profiles/runnerprofile.php?runnerid=<?php echo $resultshome['hskid']; ?>"><?php echo $resultshome['hskname']; ?></a>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                      <?php echo $resultshome['hsktname']; ?>
                    </td>
            <td>
            </td>
            <td>
            </td>
                <?php
                }
                else {
                echo "<td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td>";
                } ?>
                    <td>
                    <?php
                    if ( !empty($resultsaway) ) { ?>
                      <?php echo $resultsaway['asknum']; ?>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                      <a href="/runner/profiles/runnerprofile.php?runnerid=<?php echo $resultsaway['askid']; ?>"><?php echo $resultsaway['askname']; ?></a>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                      <?php echo $resultsaway['asktname']; ?>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <?php
                }
                else {
                echo "<td></td><td></td>";
                } ?>
                <?php } ?>
            </table>
```

Comment: Show us your loop code.

Comment: Is the SQL relevant to the question? If so, I'm not understanding what the question is. If it's not relevant remove it. It's always best to write your code examples as concise (yet functional) as possible to help users narrow in on your issue. SO even gives you guidelines how to best accomplish this: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: h, I added (now removed) the SQL as I thought this could be fixed with SQL rather than the two loops.

Comment: If the two result sets are interchangeable, other than home vs away, use one query with a `UNION` and add a column that indicates home/away status.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I cleaned up your code a bit, and took the assignment out of the loop.

```
<table>
<?php 
$keys = [
    "home" => [
        'hsknum',
        'hskid',
        'hskname',
        'hsktname',
    ],
    "away" => [
        'asknum',
        'askid',
        'askname',
        'asktname',
    ],
];
$myFunc = function($row, $inArray, $team) use ($keys) {
    if (!empty($inArray)) {
        array_push(
            $row, 
            $inArray[$keys[$team][0]], 
            sprintf(
                '<a href="/runner/profiles/runnerprofile.php?runnerid=%s">%s</a>',
                $inArray[$keys[$team][1]],
                $inArray[$keys[$team][2]]
            ),
            $inArray[$keys[$team][3]],
            "&nbsp;",
            "&nbsp;"
        );
    } else {
        $row = array_merge($row, array_fill(0, 5, "&nbsp;"));
    }
    return $row;
};
do {
    $resultshome = $rowh->fetch();
    $resultsaway = $rowa->fetch();
    if (!$resultshome && !$resultsaway) {
        break;
    }
    $row = [];
    $row = $myFunc($row, $resultshome, "home");
    $row = $myFunc($row, $resultsaway, "away");
    echo "<tr><td>", implode("</td><td>", $row), "</td></tr>";
} while (true);
?>
</table>
```

Edit: Now with home and away array keys...

I don't know anything about this game but the DB should prolly be something like this:

```
game
    id
    homeTeamId
    awayTeamId
    fromDate
    toDate

team
    id
    name

player
    id
    name

team_player
    teamId
    playerId
    fromDate
    toDate

team_game_players
    gameId
    teamId
    playerId
    number?

game_score
    gameId
    teamId
    playerId
    something?
```

Comment: Thanks, looks nice, sadly a few errors: Undefined index: hsknum -  Undefined index: hskid - Undefined index: hskname - Undefined index: hsktname.  The I get a table made of just the HOME entries??? No AWAY antries at all..

Comment: @WilsonBubbles ah yes, you named the fields differently depending on them being home or away... now with home and away array keys.

Comment: WOW, Now I would have never got close to that.  This is clean and clear to me and it works exactly as expected under all tests.  Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to open with:

```
while (( $resultshome = $rowh->fetch()) && ($resultsaway = $rowa->fetch()))
```

PHP short-circuits boolean statements, which means that in the case of (A || B), "B" will only ever be reached if "A" evaluates as false. As long as you have an OR between the conditions, you'll iterate through all of $rowh before you start $rowa.

Comment: Indeed it does line up the table in the way I want however it does not handle when $resultshome = $rowh->fetch() is empty.  When it is empty it shows nothing even when there is and entry $resultsaway = $rowa->fetch().  This why I am getting stuck on this issue.. I cant get all or both or either. thanks tho.

Comment: This will cause problems if the two result sets have different numbers of rows (e.g. 10 home games v.s. 3 away games). you'll just be getting a lot  of boolean false returns, and using that false as an array later on will just spew warnings.

Answer (score 0):

A better structure would be to separate the fetch logic from the display logic. This is especialy true if both queries can return different numbers of rows (e.g. 10 home games v.s. 5 away games)

```
$games = array();
$row = 0;
# fetch home game data
while($row = $rowh->fetch()) {
   $games[$row] = array(); // initialize this array row
   $games[$row]['home'] = $row;
   $row++;
}

$row = 0;
# fetch away game data
while($row = $rowa->fetch()) {
   $games[$row]['away'] = $row;
   $row++;
}

foreach ($games as $index => $game) {
if (isset($game['home']) { 
    ... output home stuff ...
} else {
    ... output empty cells - no home game for this particular row
}
if (isset($game['away']) {
    ... output away stuff
} else {
   ... output empty cells - no away game for this particular row
}
```